# Cannot upload files to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Microsoft ticket open that is going nowhere so I am asking here hoping someone can help.  As of late last week, suddenly, in SharePoint online, classic document libraries will no longer upload files to them.  Drag'n'Drop or clicking the upload and selecting a file results in:

"Sorry, your files couldn't be uploaded. The upload might be too large or the server might be experiencing high network traffic."

The files are less than 1MB.  This is happening in multiple libraries for multiple people, and many libraries have less than 50 items in them.  If a document library is in modern experience, it has no issues.

As a side note, I noticed along with this while troubleshooting, the affected libraries are skewed to the left, like there is no more web framing on the page.  Also, on the affected libraries, when I try to go into "Library Settings"  it goes to an error page saying "Unexpected Error has occured" and has no further details.

I made no changes to the site, and I am the only SharePoint guy at the company, hence the name...

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Not sure if you saw this blog post. Maybe the suggestions in it will help.  https://www.koskila.net/sorry-your-files-couldnt-be-uploaded-the-upload-might-be-too-large-or-the-server-might-be-experiencing-high-network-traffic/

Comment: I did see it, and custom scripts are already enabled, I am the site collection admin, the issue comes currently I cannot open library or list settings, I get the error "Unexpected Error has occurred" just trying to open the half of the settings pages on any site, including the root site.  This also means I cannot switch it to modern view. Appreciate the link though.

Comment: This won't fix classic - but maybe it will allow you to switch your lists to Modern?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-userinterface-lists-and-libraries-optout#opting-out-at-list-level

Comment: Thank you Robin.  I have considered tinkering with this prior, but didn't know if I should as I have a severity A with the SharePoint product group via Microsoft Premier Support, granted, going on a week now, still no answers... I may approach the sharepoint owner and see how they want to proceed. Thanks again